# Why these two elements are not aligned in one line?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to align these input forms to one line. If I take them separately - it works. Just trying to make it responsive. I want them to be in one line for desktop and move one below another for mobile.
I'm using these styles to create to make forms responsive and they work separately. But when I add other styles of my page there is a conflict and it's not working anymore

```
/** basic default styles **/
    html { margin: 0; padding: 0; }







    span.chyron { font-size: 1.2em; padding-top: 10px; }

    /** main blocks **/
    #container {
        display: block;
        max-width: 800px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-top: 5px;
        margin-bottom: 66px;
        padding: 20px 15px;
        background: #fff;
        border-radius: 6px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
        -moz-border-radius: 6px;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    td {
        width: 60%;
    }


    /** the form elements **/
    #hongkiat-form { box-sizing: border-box; }

    #hongkiat-form .txtinput {
        display: block;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: #dedede;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        font-size: 1.55em;
        padding: 11px 25px;
        padding-left: 55px;
        width: 90%;
        color: #777;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
        transition: border 0.15s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.15s linear 0s, color 0.15s linear 0s;
        -webkit-transition: border 0.15s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.15s linear 0s, color 0.15s linear 0s;
        -moz-transition: border 0.15s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.15s linear 0s, color 0.15s linear 0s;
        -o-transition: border 0.15s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.15s linear 0s, color 0.15s linear 0s;
    }

    #hongkiat-form .txtinput:focus {
        color: #333;
        border-color: rgba(41, 92, 161, 0.4);
        box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(41, 92, 161, 0.6);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(41, 92, 161, 0.6);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(41, 92, 161, 0.6);
        outline: 0 none;
    }

    #hongkiat-form input#name {
        background: #fff url('images/user.png') 5px 4px no-repeat;
    }
    #hongkiat-form input#email {
        background: #fff url('images/email.png') 5px 4px no-repeat;
    }
    #hongkiat-form input#website {
        background: #fff url('images/website.png') 5px 4px no-repeat;
    }
    #hongkiat-form input#telephone {
        background: #fff url('images/phone.png') 5px 4px no-repeat;
    }

    #hongkiat-form textarea {
        display: block;
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-color: #dedede;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        padding: 11px 25px;
        padding-left: 55px;
        width: 90%;
        height: 180px;
        color: #777;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
        transition: border 0.15s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.15s linear 0s, color 0.15s linear 0s;
        -webkit-transition: border 0.15s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.15s linear 0s, color 0.15s linear 0s;
        -moz-transition: border 0.15s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.15s linear 0s, color 0.15s linear 0s;
        -o-transition: border 0.15s linear 0s, box-shadow 0.15s linear 0s, color 0.15s linear 0s;
    }
    #hongkiat-form textarea:focus {
        color: #333;
        border-color: rgba(41, 92, 161, 0.4);
        box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(40, 90, 160, 0.6);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(40, 90, 160, 0.6);
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset, 0 0 8px rgba(40, 90, 160, 0.6);
        outline: 0 none;
    }


    #hongkiat-form #slider { width: 70%; }

    #hongkiat-form #aligned {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        float: left;
        width: 300px;
        margin-right: 50px;
    }
    #hongkiat-form #aside {
        float: left;
        width: 400px;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    #wrapping { width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; }

    span.radiobadge { display: block; margin-bottom: 8px; }
    span.radiobadge label { font-size: 1.2em; padding-bottom: 4px; }





    /** @group clearfix **/
    .clearfix:after { content: "."; display: block; clear: both; visibility: hidden; line-height: 0; height: 0; }
    .clearfix { display: inline-block; }

    html[xmlns] .clearfix { display: block; }
    * html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
```

Here is a jsfiddle for it:

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Luynxjf8/)

Thank you!

Comment: You need to post a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: If you look at the fiddle you posted you'll see that your HTMl is pretty messed up. For example you can't start another TABLE within a table unless it's within a TD.

Comment: Minimal version that works: https://jsfiddle.net/6ntpa5yd/

Comment: I'm strongly recommend to use a grid like [bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/), It will turn your life to much more comfortable.

Comment: @MoshFeu Why use a framework (or part of it) if that's *not* the question?

Comment: That's because no one including me didn't understand the problem because of the missy code etc. He mention that the problem start when he want to convert his design to responsive. I think, that in the most of the cases it will be faster and cleaner to implement it using bootstrap than try to fight with the code. But that's me..

Answer (score 0):

try it with flexbox:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="form1 flex-item">
  form
  </div>
  <div class="form2 flex-item">
  form2
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flex-item{
  width: 50%;

  @media (max-width: 600px){
   width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Eva, but it doesn't work. Work the same as it did for non-working version. Here is what I've done: https://jsfiddle.net/vranqjyh/